# JS to cycle through MySQL results?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Currently I have a small piece of PHP code that gets one random row from my table.

```
<?php
    if (!$query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testimonials ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1")) {
        echo 'Error: '.mysql_error().'';
    } else {
        while ($q = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $quote = $q['quote'];
            $author = $q['author'];
            echo $quote;
            echo '<br />- <strong>'.$author.'</strong>';
        }
    }
?>
```

What I'd like to do instead is have it load one when the page loads, then fade out and fade in to another one from the database.

Comment: what do you mean with _then fade out and fade in to another one from the database_ ?

Comment: I mean like on this site: http://www.jet-exchange.eu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either load several rows upfront and use JS to cycle through them in the browser, or use AJAX to request a new row from the database every time you cycle through to the next one.

I would advise the first method as it lessens the amount of queries to your database and the number of HTTP requests to your web server.